# Alternative for the deprecated People class in Android

Tags: java, android

I was writing a program to retrieve all the contacts from the Phonebook.

Here goes my code inside `onCreate`:

```
setContentView(R.layout.cursorlayout);
        ListView lv =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.cursorListView);
        String uriString = "content://contacts/people/";
        //Cursor myCursor = managedQuery(Uri.parse(uriString),null, null,null,null);
        Cursor myCursor = getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI, new String[] {People._ID, People.NAME, People.NUMBER}, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(myCursor);

        String from[] = new String[]{"People.NAME","People.NUMBER"};
        int to[] = new int[]{R.id.name,R.id.number};
        SimpleCursorAdapter s = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.simplecursorlayout,myCursor,from,to);
        lv.setAdapter(s);
```

However, eclipse marked the class "People" as deprecated.Infact the parent container "Contacts" itself is deprecated. So my question is, Is there any alternative to this class that I can use ?

Comment: Have you ever used the developers reference? http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html Just type the word People in the search box and then select the dropdown for `android.provider.Contacts.People`. It not only tells you it's deprecated but tells you what class to use instead.

Comment: Hmm...its ContactsContract. I didn't bother to look into docs. I could have done that before asking a question here.Most of the examples on internet used People, aren't they aware that its deprecated ?. Thanks a lot btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its [ContactsContract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html)!